# Building an algorithm to build a satisfiable formula from a valid existential statement

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

**Question:**

Given the following signature - $\Sigma := \lbrace R^2, P^2, c\rbrace$ (2 relations and a constant), prove/disprove:
There exists an algorithm that given an existential statement $\phi$ builds a formula $\psi$ with no quantifiers s.t. $\phi$ is valid $\iff \exists z \forall y \exists x \psi$ is satisfiable.

**My answer:**
I believe this is true, but I'm not sure about it, would like to verify my algorithm:

1. We've seen that for any formula $A^\exists$ is valid $\iff$ $A$ is satisfiable: therefore I'll remove all $\exists$ quantifiers from $\phi$ and call it $\phi'$ - it's satisfiable $\iff \phi $ is valid.
2. I'll rename variables in $\phi'$ s.t. their names won't be x,y,z.
3. I'll add the required quantifiers to $\phi'$: $\phi''=\exists z \forall y \exists x \phi'$ . Since these 3 new variables don't appear in the new formula, it's equivalent logically to $\phi'$.

This seems like too simple of a solution to be right...

Comment: Do you mean to say "$\phi$ is valid $\iff$ $\exists z \forall y \exists x \psi$ is satisfiable"?  Otherwise how is $\psi$ used?

Comment: fixed the question.